# find the smallest difference between the value and column

Tags: excel, min

I don't know why excel can't find minimum difference between my chosen value (9,1) and subtraction from numbers in column B.
Excel only calculate difference between chosen number and the first number in column B. 
Any suggestions what to do to get comparison with all results?

Date:

```
      A      B
1              
2            3
3            5
4            2
5            9
6            8
```

Formula(s) tried:

```
=MIN(ABS($B$2:$B$6-9,1))
=MIN(ABS($B$2:$B$6-C2))
```

[image: OP sample data]

Comment: Can you show what formulas you're using, the result you expect to get, and the result you're actually getting?

Comment: Can you please show what with some data, want to do?

Comment: You need to reference an array of values and determine the difference of each one,. Excel can determine the smallest difference and return that from the formula.

Comment: I don't think you can do this purely in Excel without an array formula.

Comment: Why the up-vote? Not only is the base assumption patently wrong but no sample data has been provided, no expected results shown nor any evidence at all that an original effort has been made to find a solution.

Comment: `{=MIN(ABS($B:$B-9,1))}`

Comment: In column B are numbers 3, 5, 2, 9, 8.

My formula is: =MIN(ABS($B2:$B6-9,1))

Result that I get is 6,1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can be reasonably assumed that the `9,1` in your formula is `9<point>1` then I believe you are putting the formula into the same row as the *3*.

The formula you have shown is an *array formula* that needs to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If you just hit <kbd>Enter↵</kbd> then the formula take *inference* of the value that is on the same row, hence `6,1` and not `0,1`. In short, it is only considering the *3* in B2 and not all of the values in B2:B6.

Solution: Tap <kbd>F2</kbd> like you were going to edit the formula then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd> all together.

[image: CSE with MIN]

See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I have read many time to press Ctr + Shift + Enter, but didn't know I have to be in the formula field.